# (A iff B), then (not A iff not B)?

Tags: logic

Suppose $A\Leftrightarrow B$, i.e. statement A holds if and only if statement B holds.

Does then $\neg A\Leftrightarrow\neg B$?

---

I think this is true since
$A\implies B$ implies $\neg B\implies \neg A$

and

$B\implies A$ implies $\neg A\implies\neg B$.

Hence, if $A\Leftrightarrow B$, then
$$
\neg A\implies\neg B\implies\neg A
$$
which means that 
$$
\neg A\Leftrightarrow\neg B.
$$

I think, we even have
$$
(A\Leftrightarrow B)~\Leftrightarrow~(\neg A\Leftrightarrow\neg B)
$$

Comment: What do you think? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Why don't you tell me?  What does $A \iff B$ mean?  What happens if $\lnot A$?  What happens if $\lnot B$?  What does that consequence mean?

Comment: Maybe try to make a truth table.

Answer (score 0):

The symbol $\iff$ means if inputs are both true or false. So if A and b = 0 or 1, then A $\iff$ B is true otherwise false.

The $\lnot$ means "Not", so if A = 0, $\lnot$A = 1, same thing as B and $\lnot$B. Which brings me to that A and B have to be 0 or 1, otherwise $\lnot A \iff \lnot B$ with be false.